# Make decision depending on variadic types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I know I have made the title as blurry as possible, but the sample will hopefully set the goals.

I have a `Base` class and families of `Derived` classes (classy OOD, nothing more).
Furthermore I have a function which takes variadic templates and I want to make decision depending on those templates.

```
template<typename... Ts>
void do_smth(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>& vec) {
    for (auto&& ptr: vec) {
        if the dynamic type of ptr is one of Ts.. then do smth.
    }
}
```

And I intend to call the function as this:

```
do_smth<Derived1, Derived2>(vec);
```

I know I could forward the `Ts...` to `std::variant` check with `hold_alternative` or smth like this, but I have only types not values. And to complicate the matters, my compiler is limitied with C++14 support.
Can someone please suggest some tiny/elegant solution to this?

Comment: If `Base` is a base class, what is the problem using a virtual function?

Comment: @Phil1970 because the algorithm is used in mathematical models, and if for one model the implementation can be correct, for other can be wrong. So need to make the decision on this layer.

Comment: `do_smth` should try to `dynamic_cast` to  `Derived1` and `Derived2`, and if either of them succeeds do something with the result and do nothing otherwise? Or what is `do_smth` supposed to do?

Comment: A C++17's fold expression of something like `(dynamic_cast<T *>(ptr) != NULL || ...)` should do the trick, so all you have to do is implement a fold expression in C++14 using helper templates. Pretty much any fold expression can be implemented manually, one step at a time. There must be a metric ton of examples of doing that, somewhere around here...

Comment: Perhaps a more real life-like example could help? Do you _really_ need `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Do you actually want to dispatch based on the type parameters, or on the runtime type of your objects? In the current code these are not related.

Comment: Let say that `A`, `B` and `C` derive from Base and you call `do_smth<A, C>(vec)` what if the problem having a vritual function in Base that does nothing and in A and C derives classes call `do something`. Mixing OOP and explicit type detection together increase complexity (2 ways of doing things for same class hierarchy) and increase also coupling 
 and duplication as any code that calls `do_smth` need to include the definition of all classes and repeat the same list of classes. Thus in the end, you have disadvatages of both techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And to complicate the matters, my compiler is limited with C++14 support.

C++14 ... so you have to simulate template folding...

What about something as follows?

```
template<typename... Ts>
void do_smth (std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>& vec) {

    using unused = bool[];

    for ( auto&& ptr: vec)
     {
       bool b { false };

       (void)unused { b, (b = b || (dynamic_cast<Ts*>(ptr) != nullptr))... };

       if ( b )
        { 
          // ptr is in Ts... list
        }
       else
        { 
          // ptr isn't in Ts... list
        }
    }
}
```